# Simulating OPT101 in PSPICE for TI

Tags: simulation, pspice, light-sensor

I want to simulate the OPT101 in PSPICE. PSPICE for TI does have that component. But the problem is the module responds to visible light in practical application. How can I impinge light on the module in simulation so that I can analyze the behavior of the circuit connected with it?